# Android background service class "onStartCommand" method does not perform all the code in it on device startup

Tags: android, multithreading, android-broadcastreceiver, background-service

I have a background service that i can start or stop using the app menu.
This service can also be started upon emulator device boot up. but the weird thing is i only see the toast messge upon device boot up, and the jobThread is not started... and even if i trigger from the menu.. i still see only the toast message.

But if i restart AndrodiStudio, and run the app and start the service from menu, it works fine.. seem as if the code inside `onStartCommand` gets only partially excecuted when the device restarts. what is wrong?

..the taskThread just calls a method inside same calss (this) service class that prints message to the logcat.

inside my service class:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    serviceRunning = true;
    Toast.makeText(this,"onStartCommand!...Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Thread taskThread = new Thread(new finalRunnableInnerClass(startId));
    taskThread.start(); 
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we worked on application that had to start on boot up, we noticed that very first log messages weren't written into devices' log buffers. After some investigation we came to a conclusion that it takes some time after a boot before methods of `Log` class become functional.

So, if the only indication of a new thread being functional is just a message in logcat, then it might be the case that the thread runs just fine, but log messages simply not being shown.

We resolved the issue of post-boot debugging by addition of capability to write logs into a file. Any time we would like to test post-boot functionality, we would compile the code with `WRITE_LOGS_TO_FILE` flag set, and then pull the file with logs from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! yes that actually is the case and is true!. my thread was running fine!. i confirmed that, by putting this code inside the run() method of the my backgroundService thread.

`Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`